# asp.net multiple updatepanels holding usercontrols with jquery partial postback problem

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page with several user controls in different updatepanels. The user controls includes jquery calls which are used to calculate some values and draw graphs(no server methods are called from jquery).

The problem is that, whatever updatepanel is refreshed, all of the jquery calls are processed again. I think the problem arises because i use pageload methods of the usercontrols to do jquery method calls.

I wonder whether there is a way to stop other user controls from calling their pageload methods or refreshing.

thanks in advance.

Comment: is the updatemode of all the update panels set to always. it should be conditional to ensure that all the updatepanels do not get refreshed.

Comment: all updatemodes of update panels are already set to conditional.

Comment: have you  written the pageLoad events in the user controls aspx page and not in the page in which these controls are included?

Comment: pageload events are included in the user control ascx files.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this would help...not exactly an answer

when you include custom controls on a page on rendering the controls HTML is included in the page as it is with all JavaScript and css( you can do a View page Source) and check that.

and so in effect there can be 3 pageloads in your page(the page that has the user controls included) in different  tags and as such all are getting called when any update panel refreshes.

Comment: thank you,
in fact that is the exact problem.
And I think the problem is specific to jquery with ajax because in order to use jquery in an ajax enabled user control, jquery calls should be done in pageload method not in $(document).ready method.